# Posts per Page on custom Taxonomy Template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, custom-post-type-archives

I'd like to show 20 posts on my custom tax template, using this filter:

```
function customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display ( $query ) {
    if ( ( $query->is_main_query()) && ( is_tax() ) ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '20' );
        $query->set( 'number_posts', '20' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        return;

    }
}

//Hook the function

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display' );
```

If I set it to `2`, two posts are shown. If I set it to `20`, `12` posts are shown. There are never more than 12 posts displayed, although 34 are published.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

`number_posts` is not a valid parameter in `pre_get_posts`, you should be using `posts_per_page`

You should also include a check (`!is_admin()`) in your query to check whether you are on the front end or back end as `pre_get_posts` alters back end queries as well

Rewrite your code to the following:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) 
{
    if (    !is_admin() 
         && $query->is_main_query() 
         && $query->is_tax() 
    ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '20'   );
        $query->set( 'orderby',        'rand' );
    }
});
```

Comment: I changed it and still get not more than 12 posts returned...